# Integer is not being shown as die() argument?

Tags: php, debugging, int, behavior

I have this strange problem. When debugging, I have sometimetimes code looking like this

```
<?php
$var = 15;
die($var);
```

`die()` function works, but outputs nothing

However, this one works

```
<?php
$var = 15;
die($var."<-");
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/81462.php

How is it possible? Did I miss something? or is it bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php (die() is equivalent to exit())

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.

Comment: Yes, so I totally missed that. Thank you.

Comment: i.e., use `$var = '15'` if you want it to print.

Comment: @Matthew: I never use '' for numbers

Answer (score 1):

`die()` is the same as `exit()`, looking at the exit docs it takes 1 parameter, `$status`, the parameter information states

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0 is used to terminate the program successfully.
>
> Note: PHP >= 4.2.0 does NOT print the status if it is an integer.

Self-explanatory really, if you want to pass a number you need to type it to a string like so:

```
die( (string)$code );
```

Comment: I know it's horror to use "$code", but wouldn't it do the same?

Comment: no, if the variable passes is an integer then it's process for internal exiting only, if it's a string regardless weather numeric it will process as output

Answer (score 0):

**die()** function needs a string parameter.

In your second example

```
die($var."<-");
```

$var is converted into String before concat with "**<-**". So this line will print out "**15<-**". This is normal. There is neither a bug nor any thing wrong.