# Function works, but can't be +1'ed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, number-formatting

I am receiving the last sort value out of 3 tables, the function works perfectly but I can't +1 the value that I return from the function. I **do not get ANY errors**, do you guys see what I am doing wrong?

What did I try?

- Using intval in the function
- Using brackets around the calculation
- A lot more

Code link: http://pastecloud.net/ZDR2JgSbIN

```
die(lastSort());
```

Displays 1, or whatever the last value is.

```
$last = lastSort();
$new = $last+1;
die($new);
```

Displays a white page

What is wrong?

Comment: Try `var_dump($new);` instead of `die($new);` and make sure it's still integer.

Comment: @starky I am getting an int(2) now, so I think it magicly started working?

Comment: It's not magic, it's just how `die()` works by specification. It doesn't display anything if you pass an integer as a status parameter. You can read documentation here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913336/1486897) answer:

> `die()` is the same as `exit()`, looking at the exit docs it takes 1
>   parameter, $status, the parameter information states.
>
> ...If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed.

So, if you want to `die()` an integer, you should first convert it to a string. Like this way: `die( (string)$new );`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that the function return the correct value, you can try to convert the **result** to an int.

```
$last = intval(lastSort());
$new = $last+1;
```

***But*** if `lastSort` returns a array (empty or non-empty), `intval` will return 0 or 1 respectively. Which could mess up you whole logic.