# Getting nothing even thru there is a value (Birthday)

Tags: php

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $email          = $_POST['email'];
        $viewemail      = $_POST['viewemail'];
        $gender         = $_POST['gender'];
        $birthdayyear   = 0 + $_POST['birthdayyear'];
        $birthdaymonth  = 0 + $_POST['birthdaymonth'];
        $birthdayday    = 0 + $_POST['birthdayday'];
        $country        = 0 + $_POST['country'];
        $lang       = 0 + $_POST['lang'];
        $favpet     = $_POST['favpet'];

        if (strlen($birthdayyear) == 2)  {
        $fourdig = date_create_from_format('y', $birthdayyear);
        $birthdayyear = date_format($fourdig, 'Y');
        if ($birthdayyear > date('Y'))
        $birthdayyear = $birthdayyear - 100;
        }


    die($birthdayyear);
```

the page will not display the value, but if i write die('sd'.$birthdayyear); I'll get "sd1988". This is when I'm posting the value "1988" but for some reason it works if I just post "88".. So what am I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Share `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: So you want it to work only if `$birthdayyear` is `1988`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer is not being shown as die() argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913312/integer-is-not-being-shown-as-die-argument)

Comment: Array ( [email] => mattias.****@hotmail.com [viewemail] => no [gender] => male [birthdayyear] => 1988 [birthdaymonth] => 05 [birthdayday] => 06 [showdate] => 1 [showyear] => 1 [country] => 2 [lang] => 1 [favpet] => [post] => Update Profile Settings! )

Comment: DrKey: No, its to update your profile on a site.

Comment: My advice is to actually *disallow* two-digit years entirely (yes, even on input). Force the user to enter an *actual* year and a lot of problems just disappear.

Comment: $birthday = date("Ymd", strtotime($birthdayyear.$birthdaymonth.$birthdayday));

Ends up 19700101 when it should be 19880506

Comment: Please explain `if (strlen($birthdayyear) == 2)` this ?

Comment: If the value has 2 numbers it will convert it to a four-digit number instead

Comment: I got it to work if I did this:

`$bday1 = 'A'.$birthdayyear.'-'.$birthdaymonth.'-'.$birthdayday.'';
$bday2 = str_replace('A','',$bday1);
$birthday = date("Ymd", strtotime($bday2));`

But I should not need to do that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added "0 + **(int)**$_POST[]" was the right solution to this. thanks Shane Henry. Anyway, heres the working code if someone wants it

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$birthdayyear   = 0 + (int)$_POST['birthdayyear'];
$birthdaymonth  = 0 + (int)$_POST['birthdaymonth'];
$birthdayday    = 0 + (int)$_POST['birthdayday'];

    if (strlen($birthdayyear) == 2)  { // if the year value is "88", it will convert it to a four digit number.
        $birthdayyear = date_format(date_create_from_format('y', $birthdayyear), 'Y');
    if ($birthdayyear > date('Y')) // if the year is over the present year
        $birthdayyear = $birthdayyear - 100; // 2035 will become 1935
    }

$birthday = date("Ymd", strtotime($birthdayyear.'-'.$birthdaymonth.'-'.$birthdayday)); // returns "YYYYmmdd"
echo $birthday;
}
```

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should check type of variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to subtract 100 from a date object. That will not work. You have to subtract from an integer. Also to compare dates this way both variables have to be a date object. So I added that as well. Fully tested and working!

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $email          = $_POST['email'];
    $viewemail      = $_POST['viewemail'];
    $gender         = $_POST['gender'];
    $birthdayyear   = 0 + (int)$_POST['birthdayyear'];
    $birthdaymonth  = 0 + (int)$_POST['birthdaymonth'];
    $birthdayday    = 0 + (int)$_POST['birthdayday'];
    $country        = 0 + (int)$_POST['country'];
    $lang           = 0 + (int)$_POST['lang'];
    $favpet         = $_POST['favpet'];

    if (strlen($birthdayyear) == 2)  {
        $birthdayyear = DateTime::createFromFormat('y', $birthdayyear);
        $birthdayyear->format('Y');
    }
    else {
        $birthdayyear = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y', $birthdayyear);
    }

    if ($birthdayyear > date('Y')) {
        $birthdayyear = (int)$birthdayyear->format('Y');
        $birthdayyear = $birthdayyear - 100;
    }

    echo $birthdayyear;
    exit;

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why are you subtracting 100 from the birth year anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines should get you what you want. date_create_from_format with a 2 digit year assumes the date will be within the 1970-2069 time window according to the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
<?php

$day = 10;
$month = 12;
$year = 88;

$format = strlen($year) == 2 ? "y-m-d" : "Y-m-d";

$dt = date_create_from_format($format, $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day)->format("Y-m-d");

echo $dt;
```

Check it out [here](https://3v4l.org/2qnWS)

Comment: Yes, I know, thats why I did like this

`if ($birthdayyear > date('Y')) // if the year is over the present year
$birthdayyear = $birthdayyear - 100; // 2035 will become 1935`