# Cannot retrieve a data - Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to fetch an ID data from `$request->user()` which is stored in `$user` variable as follow:
`$user = $request->user();`
When I try to check the `$user` value by using `die($user)` it give me :

`{
  "id": 3,
  "firstname": "Firstname Value",
  "lastname": "Lastname Value",,
  "username": "usernamevalue",
  "email": ""email@mail.com","
}`

It think there's no problem here and everything is good. But when I try to fetch the `id` by `$user->id`, it gives me nothing. But when I try by using `var_dump($user->id)` it give me `int(3)`. And when I try `die($user->username)`, it gives me the username value. Can you tell me why this happens? And how to fix this. Thank you.

EDIT by adding dd() results :

```
#fillable: array:6 [
    0 => "firstname"
    1 => "lastname"
    2 => "username"
    3 => "email"
  ]
  #hidden: array:2 [
    0 => "password"
    1 => "remember_token"
  ]
  #casts: array:1 [
    "email_verified_at" => "datetime"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "users"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:16 [
    "id" => 3
    "firstname" => "Firstname Value"
    "lastname" => "Lastname Value"
    "username" => "usernamevalue"
    "email" => "email@mail.com"
    "created_at" => "2020-03-06 00:07:35"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-06 00:07:35"
  ]
  #original: array:16 [
    "id" => 3
    "firstname" => "Firstname Value"
    "lastname" => "Lastname Value"
    "username" => "usernamevalue"
    "email" => "email@mail.com"
    "created_at" => "2020-03-06 00:07:35"
    "updated_at" => "2020-03-06 00:07:35"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
```

Comment: Did you try to ```json_decode($request->user())``` ? I don't know if that could work but sometimes it does.

Comment: Yes I've tried. But it's still can't fetch the id value, but can fetch the username.

Comment: Can you do a ```dd($request->user());``` and show the result ?

Comment: Sure, my question just edited.

Comment: Well... Pretty strange... The only difference is that your **id** is an integer, can you do ```(string) $user->id``` to see if you get it (that will not solve our problem) ? How do you fetch your data ? Can I see your code ? If you replace ```$request->user()``` by ```Auth::user()``` does it works ?

Comment: If I try using `dd()`, `echo`, `var_dump()` it's work fine to fetch the `id` value. But not for `die()`. I'm using JWT Auth for the authentication. Why I'm asking this is to get another data which is require the `user_id`. Yeah it's weird. Oh in my user's migration file, I used the bigIncrements for the id. Is it fine?

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913312/integer-is-not-being-shown-as-die-argument ```die()``` is the same as ```exit()``` and does not print integers, it uses integer values. And yes, bigIncrements is totally fine. So I think you can convert your id into string before using ```die()```

Comment: Hey, do dd($request->id); show us.

Comment: It returns the ID Value if I'm using `dd($user->id)`.